# How to display list errors in thymeleaf?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

Here is a sample skeleton of DTO object.

```
public class MyDTO
{
    List<Student> students=new ArrayList<>();
}

public class Student
{
    String name;
    Integer age;
    // setter and getter methods
}
```

Now, the user has a chance to enter a lot of students into the list and any student detail might contain an error. The possible errors are student age being greater than 25, and name containing special characters etc.

For example, `students[2].name` has a special character and `student[4].age` > 25, then they are errors. Now, I would like to display the error below those fields and also highlight the corresponding fields.

```
<form th:field="${myDTO}">
    <input type="text" th:field="*{students[0].name}" th:errorclass="fieldError"/>
    <span class="error" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('students[0].name')}" th:errors="*{students[0].name}"></span>
    <input type="number" th:field="*{students[0].age}" min="15" max="25" th:errorclass="fieldError"/>
    <span class="error" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('students[0].age')}" th:errors="*{students[0].age}"></span>
</form>
```

I am confused on what to put in `th:field` attribute? When I write as above, such type of error is the result

> Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name
>   'students+'['+0+']'' available as request attribute.

In my validators, I have such type of code..

```
    int idx=0;
    for(Student st: students)
    {
        errors.pushNestedPath("students["+idx+"]");
        ValidationUtils.invokeValidator(studentValidator, st, errors);
        errors.popNestedPath();         
        idx++;
    }
```

and in the `StudentValidator` class..

```
@Override
public void validate(Object obj, Errors errors) {
    Student s=(Student) obj;
    if(containsSpecialCharacters(s.name))
    {
        errors.rejectValue("name","name.containsSpecialCharacters",null,null);
    }
    if(s.age>25 || s.age<15)
    {
        errors.rejectValue("age","age.invalid",null,null);
    }
}
```

Now, my problems are

1. How do I show those errors, highlight the corresponding fields?
2. What to put in the `th:field` tag?
3. Next, the student records are added dynamically, that is the student rows doesn't exist previously, by clicking on **Add student** button, the user will be able to add the student. Now, even the `th:field` must also be updated. How to do that, because it is related to thymeleaf template processing which is done previously but not after the page is loaded?

Hope you will reply as soon as possible.

Answer (score 1):

your validation seems to be right, but maybe you need to pass a `BindingResult` as parameter in your controller so that the error can be retrieved in your view layer.

```
@PostMapping("/students")
public String saveStudent(@Valid Student, BindingResult bindingResult, RedirectAttributes redirAttrs) {

    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        // Show errors here
        bindingResult.getAllErrors().stream().forEach(System.out::println);
        return "student-edit";
    } else {
        Long id = releaseLogService.save(student).getId();
        redirAttrs.addFlashAttribute("message", "Success");
        return "redirect:/student/edit/" + id;
    }
}
```